# Software to create a list of folders, open that list by a shortcut and move/drag & drop files into (similar to quick access menu)

Tags: windows, directories

I often end up with tens and hundreds of different files on my downloads folder on daily basis that i have to organize by going through them, selecting, cutting, navigating, and pasting files to their appropriate folders scattered all over the hard drive.. you can imagine how time consuming that is specially when it has to be done daily...

I need a software that allows me to create a list of folders, open that list by a shortcut and move or drag & drop files into (something similar to quick access menu or navigation pane) unfortunately my quick access menu and navigation pane are already all crowded and used up for other work purposes..

Best solution I have so far is using the send to feature in the right-click context menu by customizing the list of folders on it.. but i thought there might be a more elegant solution out there.

Thank you in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Looks like a scripting task to me - a job for Powershell, Perl, Python, Bash...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use a file-manager that has a quick-jump feature built in.

#### File Managers

Check out the Open-Source [Double Commander](http://doublecommander.com/) or it's Shareware inspiration [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/download.htm).

**Double Commander** is my daily driver, and because of the side-by-side panel approach you always have your `Downloads` folder in view, and on the other side you can change directories quickly with `Ctrl`+`D`

For Windows 10 there is an interesting "new breed" of File Manager called [OneCommander](https://www.onecommander.com/) that might be suitable as well.

Bonus: On Linux I would recommend the text-mode [ranger](https://ranger.github.io/). On the graphical side Double Commander should work - but I don't have any experience there with it.

#### Windows Explorer

If sticking with Windows-Explorer is important, you can create a "jump-folder" filled with shortcuts (.lnk files) to destination folders, and have that "jump-folder" sit on your desktop or in your Quick Access section.

This way you can drag-n-drop, as well as reach those folders quickly.

### UPDATE

I stumbled on this while looking for something completely different.
Check out [Direct Folders](https://alternativeto.net/software/direct-folders/about/), that sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: tyvm for the recommendation, but unfortunately i'm sticking with Windows Explorer because i'm using Clover with it and i really like it.. what i ended up doing is using AutoHotKey with a customized "Send To" Menu.. it's not perfect but it definitely made things a little more snappy

Comment: Isn't Clover filled with adware ?
[5y old reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4uqswo/new_version_of_clover_out_310_tabbed_windows/d96tkpy/)

Comment: i'm not sure about that to be honest... i think it just gets a bad rep for being a chinese software... what i know is that it definitely revolutionized my file explorer experience.. and thank you for "direct folders" looks promising, i'll give it a try

Comment: Oh boy, I just downloaded [Clover](http://en.ejie.me/), intrigued by your comments, and [VirusTotal is very opinionated](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/9847281c4caca7b50d73839b8d1a8426a16d55c551ebd55c5854f29bcf517910) about it. I'm going to install it in a VM first. Are you sure you want to stick with this one?

Comment: I just installed Clover, Just to be clear - it's a tabbed interface for Explorer - any other features? The installer is in Chinese I unchecked both check-boxes, one is machine translated to "I have read and accepted the user can pull the privacy change cover" (and somehow it allowed me to install) - I'll try copying it over from the VM, and see if it works. I'll also be looking for alternatives to Clover - the VirusTotal flagging was too scary.